# How can I build a complex polymorphic association which includes ActiveResource classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, activeresource, tournament

I'm attempting to build a diverse [tournament management system](https://github.com/colindean/plas) which allows multiple types of tournament bracket backends. The goal is to provide a very simple option for the tournament bracket backend (here, `PlasTournament`) and the possibility of multiple, more elaborate backends (right now, just `Challonge::Tournament`, which is from [Challonge](http://challonge.com/), using the [challonge-api](https://bitbucket.org/corneldm/challonge-api/wiki/Home) gem via its [API](http://challonge.com/api)).

My models:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event 
  validates :event, :presence => true
  has_one :remote, :as => :tournament_bracket, :dependent => :destroy
end

class PlasTournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :winner, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :tournament_bracket, :polymorphic => true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :participants, :class_name => "User"
end
```

There's also [`Challonge::Tournament`](https://bitbucket.org/corneldm/challonge-api/src/8a7d1d9c08d4/lib/challonge/tournament.rb), but I'm not sure how to get it to fit this style. Do I need to monkeypatch it? It's an ActiveResource class and I really only need to store in the polymorphic association in the `Tournament` class its class and id.

I previously had these models:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event 
  validates :event, :presence => true
  has_one :remote_tournament, :as => :tournament_bracket, :dependent => :destroy
end

class RemoteTournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament_bracket, :polymorphic => true

  def tournament_bracket_type_type=(sType)
     super(sType.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
  end
end

class PlasTournament < RemoteTournament
  belongs_to :winner, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :tournament_bracket, :polymorphic => true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :participants, :class_name => "User"
end
```

or something like that. It didn't work, and I didn't commit it like I did the above.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this in my controller's `create` method (and I know some of this could be handled by passing `params[:tournament]` to #new; I'm just being explicit for this example):

```
@tournament = Tournament.new
@tournament.event = params[:tournament][:event_id]
@tournament.name = params[:tournament][:name]
@remote = params[:tournament][:remote_type].constantize.new
#set its state
@tournament.remote = @remote
@tournament.save!
```

and then later on in `Tournament#show` do something like this:

```
@tournament = Tournament.find params[:id]
#the only things I need from Tournament are the 
#name, description, max_participants, and remote
@remote = @tournament.remote
#^this is primarily for shorthand access
```

Then, in the view, I can pass off to certain partials or widgets based on the class of the `remote`.

```
case remote.class
when PlasTournament
  render :partial => 'brackets/plas'
when Challonge::Tournament
  render :partial => 'brackets/challonge'
end
```

Am I off my rocker? This seems fairly straightforward, but I think I'm caught in the implementation details of Rails.

What I'm looking for is essentially a way to have polymorphic tournament bracketing systems hidden behind a tournament class.